# Github showing preview in searches

Tags: github, github-actions, github-api

**Hello guys.**
I would like to know if there is any way to search on **Github**, which shows at least one image of the prints that are in the project.

Because I research many web **templates**, and this consumes a lot of my time, and load of guithub itself so that I download SC one by one, just to choose which one suits me best.

I searched all over the web and didn't find anything about it.

**Thanks!**

Comment: What are "images of prints"?

Comment: Hi @rethab

Embedded in the body of the main text.
**Example on Page link:**
[Github Page](https://github.com/Timocop/PNG-to-JPG-Analysis)

**Embedded Image:**
[Image](https://camo.githubusercontent.com/05347de6a68ce317a0f32b043bb4bc79bfdf9a8e16f98f0b5f87cc427db46748/68747470733a2f2f692e696d6775722e636f6d2f5057774d4966782e706e67)

Comment: I don't understand your question. Can you please describe the exact steps you're performing? Also, here are some hints on how to ask: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Ok @rethab

Sorry, English is not my first language.

First step, I'm searching for a web template, for example:
Netflix template "html with css", to use as a basis for me to create a new landpage.

When I do a search on the github search engine, it shows me the following results, but none with a screenshot of the template.

**Search on github**
![IMAGE 1](https://imgur.com/3EVV96C)

**Search on Google**
![IMAGE 2](https://imgur.com/eQTU8vU)

So, I want to find a way to search on github only repositories that have screenshot "print screens", templates, or themes, etc.

Comment: Have you tried [GitHub's Code Search](https://cs.github.com). Perhaps you could search for repositories that contain the string "![" in their README plus some more keywords.

Comment: Good idea **@rethab**, I have looked through the github search engine but still haven't seen this. I'll take a look, if it works I'll come back here and mark the question as answered. Thank you for now

Comment: Thanks a lot for the tip @rethab **GitHub's Code Search**, I'll use it. However, when I created an account they put me on a waiting list. Now the way is to wait!